# find commands too old for history

Tags: command-history

I am trying to find commands executed on my xen server yesterday - but the oldest command to be seen with history dates from today. Is there a way to see older commands (history displays 380 latest commands on my server)?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? What number do you get when you execute `echo $HISTSIZE` in a terminal window?

Comment: I get 1000. I am on CentOS 7

Comment: @GAD3R That would be the future-oriented solution. But this question looks like it wants to find commands that are no longer in the `HISTORY` (which is probably not possible).

Comment: Restore your history file from last night's backup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your yesterday's history is gone (if not within the 380 lines).
Just guessing: Your `HISTFILESIZE` shell variable is set to around that value. That's "the  maximum  number  of lines contained in the history file." (man bash) which persist across logout / logins. Try setting higher.

Comment: That's going forward; doesn't answer the actual question.